# JSF redirect after EJBException

Tags: jsf, redirect, jpa

I'm using JSF with JPA. My error handling is done by a global exception handler which will be triggered if any error occurs. In this handler, I just perform a redirect to my error.xhtml.

This works fine except for the JPA handlers. If the @EJB jpa handlers produce an error, I get it, in my case, as an EJB exception. In this case, the jsf redirect doesn't work.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/error/");
```

But I don't get any error message. I think this is related to some lifecycle problem, but I don't have any clue how to solve it. I just want to achieve a global error handling with jpa and jsf, which will always end at one specific error page :(

Answer (score 0):

Do you catch Exceptions with some jsf mechanism?

If yes maybe JSF missed those JPA exceptions. You could the try to catch those via web.xml:

```
<error-page>
       <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
       <location>/error_redirect.html</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error_redirect.html</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error_redirect.html</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
       <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
       <location>/error_redirect.html</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
       <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
       <location>/error_redirect.html</location>
</error-page>
```

And in "error_redirect.html" you could redirect to "/faces/error.xhtml" or whatever.

Maybe you can also directly point those entries to "/error/" but for some reason (which i don't remember) i used this redirection html :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I followed the following tutorial http://wmarkito.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/adding-global-exception-handling-using-jsf-2-x-exceptionhandler/ .. the exception handler will be called in this case but only the redirect doesn't work. I think the facesContext is wrong because of the EJB?